# Multiple Graphical Issues on ASUS TUF DASH F15

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

My laptop is nvidia-optimus powered and has led to multiple headaches regarding Ubuntu 20.04. Currently, the system is in a state where it works kinda fine for a bit, but has frequent graphical glitches for a few frames before returning back to normal; it **appears** the glitches only occur whenever I move a window or cursor. Usually, these glitches are weird in that one half of the screen switches sides with the other, though sometimes leads to a black-screen crash where the system works perfectly fine (I can still do CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal) but I can't see anything nor switch tty.

The system uses:

- RTX 3070 and integrated Intel Xe Graphics
- Proprietary nvidia driver (nvidia 460 non-server via GUI) with open-source intel driver
- xorg server that only uses the RTX 3070

Here is more detail about what I did / tried:

- Arch linux surprisingly works perfectly fine with GNOME and Kernel 5.11 (or so), but I've only tested it with integrated graphics
- Ubuntu actually wasn't able to boot at all when I first installed it, but uninstalling xserver-xorg-video-nouveau via a chroot forced it to use Intel graphics, then I was able to access the system and install the proprietary driver for nvidia.
- When a graphical glitch occured, they never showed up in ~/.local/share/xorg/. Haven't checked when it crashes however
- In Ubuntu 20.04, the same thing happens with integrated or dedicated graphics.
- Adding nomodeset to the kernel's parameters crashes my system on boot (stuck on ASUS' splashscreen)

I'm stuck on what to do, since I would like to have Ubuntu for specific software. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The machine relies on quite a few recent kernel updates, which means you will need to install a version of Ubuntu that has kernel 5.14 or newer. 21.10 should give you a properly functional system 

Comment: Just installed Ubuntu 21.10 and it worked like a charm. Interestingly enough, it's still kernel 5.13? Weird how that works

Comment: For anyone else with this issue who still wants to use Ubuntu 20.04, I tried out the PopOS NVIDIA version and it also dealt with the drivers super easily + allowed me to change between discrete and integrated graphics

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else with this issue who still wants to use Ubuntu 20.04, I tried out the PopOS NVIDIA version and it also dealt with the drivers super easily + allowed me to change between discrete and integrated graphics. Optionally, you could try manually updating the kernel via a chroot or something.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps? I am facing the same issue. I am however kind of reluctant to switch OSes, but is there a workaround without it (I am using 22.04)?